# string is not getting converted properly while setting it from ssh command

Tags: string, bash, docker, ssh

This is my actions file which is running the ssh command to ssh into my workstation with given parameters and calling `deployer.sh` file.

```
MOUNT_ECR_LOGIN="-v /usr/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login:/usr/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login"

ACTIONS="${WORKSTATION_EC2} MOUNT_ECR_LOGIN=$MOUNT_ECR_LOGIN ./deployer.sh"
```

which gets converted into the following string while running:

```
ssh -t -t -q ec2-user@networkba-bastion ssh -q -t ec2-user@workstation MOUNT_ECR_LOGIN=-v /usr/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login:/usr/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login ./deployer.sh
```

Below is the error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login:/usr/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login: No such file or directory
```

I am setting up the variable for `deployer.sh` file which is running the docker run command.

unfortunately, the `MOUNT_ECR_LOGIN` is assigned as -v only and not the full string with file information. Am I supposed to escape the spaces here? or we need some other solution?

Comment: Your command is too long. Could you simplify it a bit to make it more readable to those who'd like to help?

Comment: I have simplified it

Answer (score 0):

## updated

The issue is due to argument splitting, because of the two ssh the arguments must be quoted twice

```
MOUNT_ECR_LOGIN=$'\'"-v /usr/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login:/usr/bin/docker-credential-ecr-login"\''

ACTIONS="${WORKSTATION_EC2} MOUNT_ECR_LOGIN=$MOUNT_ECR_LOGIN ./deployer.sh"
```

## previous answer was

, a quick fix could be to use arrays

```
ACTIONS=("${WORKSTATION_EC2}" "SOURCE_REGISTRY=$SOURCE_REGISTRY" "DEPLOYMENT_NAME=$DEPLOYMENT_NAME" "MOUNT_ECR_LOGIN=$MOUNT_ECR_LOGIN" ./deployer.sh)
```

and then use `"${ACTIONS[@]}"`

Comment: seems that may be due to double ssh which result in parsing arguments twice and splitting after the `-v`, have you tried removing the space after `-v` otherwise you will have to pass environment variable through a sourced file

Comment: I did the same for the resolution as nothing else worked.